# Angle that a moving ball will bounce off of an inert ball

Tags: java, math, physics, collision

Let there be two balls, one of which is moving about in the Cartesian coordinate plane, while the other is stationary and immobile. At some point, the moving ball collides with the inert ball. Assuming the moving ball is traveling in a straight line, how can one derive the new angle that the moving ball will be propelled given the following information:

The  moving ball's center coordinates (X0, Y0), radius (R0), and angle of travel before impact (A0)

The stationary ball's center coordinates (X1, Y1) and radius (R1)

Comment: This isn't really programming-related.

Comment: Vector Mechanics-101 Overflow?

Comment: There's a lot of ball motion questions on Stack Overflow, one of which has about 70 stars. This one is similar to those, but not exactly the same. And since I'm programming it right now, its programming-related to me.

Comment: draw it on paper and the equations will fall out.

Comment: There are a lot of people here thinking that if it isn't code, then it isn't programming related. Life is much more complicated than that

Comment: @belisarius: indeed! Many thanks for the tutorial!

Comment: Who's got the biggest balls of them all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your second ball has infinite mass:

[image]

Where phi (after a long calc) is:

```
phi=  -ArcTan[
         ( 2 R^2 Sin[A0] + 2 (YD Cos[A0] - XD Sin[A0]) (2 H Cos[A0] + 
           2 XD Sin[A0]^2 - YD Sin[2 A0]))  /
         ((2 R^2 - XD^2 - 3 YD^2) Cos[A0] + (XD^2 - YD^2) Cos[3 A0] + 
           8 XD YD Cos[A0]^2 Sin[A0] + 4 H Sin[A0] (-YD Cos[A0] + XD Sin[A0]))
           ]
```

Where:

```
H   = (R0 + R1)^2 - ((Y0 - Y1) Cos[A0] + (X0 - X1) Sin[A0])^2  
R^2 = (R0 + R1)^2
XD  =  X1 - X0
YD  =  Y1 - Y0
```

**Edit**

To determine the whole trajectory, you'll also need the coordinates for the center of the moving ball at the time of impact. They are:

```
  {X,Y}= {X1+Sin[A0] ((Y1-Y0) Cos[A0]+ (X0-X1) Sin[A0])-Cos[A0] Sqrt[H],
          Y1+Cos[A0] ((Y0-Y1) Cos[A0]+(-X0+X1) Sin[A0])-Sin[A0] Sqrt[H]}
```

Comment: Thanks guy. I'll implement it and see how it goes.

Comment: @farm Remember to use atan2 to evade those tricky +/- Pi problems

Comment: @belisarius, is that autocad? where's the typical clean mma animation that goes along with your answers? ;) +1

Comment: @R. M. This is [`Geometry Expressions`](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/). Geometric problems with non-punctual masses, usually end up in complicated equations. Everything is always easier in the center-of-mass system. But that is not the best for playing a game :)

Comment: @belisarius, I coded the function, and it seems to be generating reasonable output. How do I use atan2 w/ this? (Java implements it as atan2(double, double)). Much appreciated.

Comment: @belisarius: That is a pretty neat product! Gotta check it out today

Comment: @farm Note that the ARCTAN in my code has the form ARCTAN[ x / y], you should use atan2(x,y) .... or atan2(y,x), I really don't remember now :(

Comment: @farmer If you are getting NaN, that probably means phi=+/-Pi/2, and so the tan[ ] is infinite. Just control the overflow

Comment: It's getting closer... no more NaNs and its bouncing correct sometimes. What's a good way to take the arctan value and extend it from 0 to 2 pi (or -pi to pi)? The phi values being generated only range from -pi/2 to pi/2. Arctan2 isn't working so well for me. In the past I would identify the quadrant and mess around with Pi +- phi. Thanks.

Comment: @farm atan2 is the way to go. Perhaps you should post another question about its usage, so we can see your code snippet

Answer (score 4):

Page 3 of [Pool Hall Lessons by Joe van den Heuvel, Miles Jackson](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php) gives a great example of how to do this.

```
// First, find the normalized vector n from the center of circle1 to the center of circle2
Vector n = circle1.center - circle2.center;
n.normalize();
// Find the length of the component of each of the movement vectors along n. 
float a1 = v1.dot(n);
float a2 = v2.dot(n);

float optimizedP = (2.0 * (a1 - a2)) / (circle1.mass + circle2.mass);

// Calculate v1', the new movement vector of circle1
// v1 = v1 - optimizedP * m2 * n
Vector v1 = v1 - optimizedP * circle2.mass * n;

// Calculate v2', the new movement vector of circle2
// v2 = v2 + optimizedP * m1 * n
Vector v2 = v2 + optimizedP * circle1.mass * n;

circle1.setMovementVector(v1);
circle2.setMovementVector(v2);
```

Read at least page three to understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the [`elastic collision`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) article on wikipedia. I would explain here, but everything I could have said, wikipedia says it better and with clear examples and equations.

Answer (score 2):

[A long, long time ago I studied this as an undergrad. ]

You need to be clear on the masses. Probably you are assuming equal mass for both balls, as opposed to one being of infinite mass.

The second thing is: Are you interested in considering rolling constraints as well as linear momentum. The treatments you will come across which talk along the lines of a simplistic elastic collision ignore all this. As an example, consider shots in pool/ snooker where you deliberately strike the ball away from the midpoint to generate front or backspin.

Do you want to able to do this?

If so, you need to consider the friction between a spinning ball and the surface.

For example in a "simple" straight-on collision between a rolling ball and a stationary one, if we assume perfectly elastic (again not quite true):

- the initial collision stops the moving ball 'A'
- the stationary ball 'B' starts moving at the impact speed of 'A'
- 'A' still has spin, it grips the surface and picks up some small velocity
- 'B' starts without spin and has to match it to its speed in order to roll. This results in it slowing slightly.

For the simplistic case, the calculation is much easier if you transform to the coordinates of the centre of mass. In that frame, the collision is always a straight-on collision, reversing the direction of the balls. You then just transform back to get the resultants.

Assuming indetical masses and speeds prior to the impact of v1 and w1.

```
V0 = centre of mass speed = (v1+w1)/2
v1_prime = v of mass_1 in transformed coords = v1 - V0
w1_prime = w1 - V0
```

Post collision, we have a simple reflection:

```
v2_prime = -v1_prime  (== w1_prime)
w2_prime = -vw_prime  (== v1_prime)

v2 = v2_prime + V0
w2 = w2_prime + V0
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply reflects from the stationary ball. So compute the point of contact (the centres of the balls will be R0 + R1 apart) and the axis of reflection will be the line joining the centres.

EDIT: By which I mean the line joining the centres at the point of contact will have an angle, and you can use this angle to help compute the new angle of the moving ball.

Comment: What if the vector between centers is at an angle to the velocity vector of the incoming ball?  You have to transform to the "centers" coordinate system to calculate the components and then transform back.

Comment: @duffymo Typically the two vectors will be at an angle. The moving ball will then be reversed and deflected by twice that angle. (If there is no angle this means that the first ball was aimed directly at the second.)

Comment: I think you are spot on Neil but you need to edit to make it clear that it is the angle at the point of contact. I.e. if ball 1 is hit at its bottom (270 degrees) spot it will travel in opposite direction and the same goes for the 0 ball for where it makes contact.

Comment: Of course the 0 ball will travel perpendicular to the 1 ball.