# How to make two balls collide and deflect in opposite directions?

Tags: java, android

I have written the code for movement of two balls within a rectangle(canvas). The balls deflect in opposite direction when they hit the top, bottom, left or right of the rectangle. But,I've tried in vain to make the balls collide with each other and deflect in opposite direction. I have searched many sites and articles but in vain. Can someone please help.

This is MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.movements;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MovementView(this));
}
}
```

This is MovementView.java

```
package com.example.movements;
public class MovementView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private int xPos,xPos1;
private int yPos,yPos1;
private int xVel,xVel1;
private int yVel,yVel1;
private int width;
private int height;
private int circleRadius,circleRadius1;
private Paint circlePaint,circlePaint1;
UpdateThread updateThread;
public MovementView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    circleRadius = 10;
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    xVel = 10;
    yVel = 10;
    circleRadius1 = 10;
    circlePaint1 = new Paint();
    circlePaint1.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    xVel1 = 11;
    yVel1 = 11;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, circleRadius, circlePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(xPos1, yPos1, circleRadius1, circlePaint1);

}
public void updatePhysics() {
    xPos += xVel;
    yPos += yVel;
    if (yPos - circleRadius < 0 || yPos + circleRadius > height) {
        if (yPos - circleRadius < 0) {
            yPos = circleRadius;
        }else{
            yPos = height - circleRadius;
        }
        yVel *= -1;
    }
    if (xPos - circleRadius < 0 || xPos + circleRadius > width) {
        if (xPos - circleRadius < 0) {
            xPos = circleRadius;
        } else {
            xPos = width - circleRadius;
        }
        xVel *= -1;
    }
    xPos1 += xVel1;
    yPos1 += yVel1;
    if (yPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0 || yPos1 + circleRadius1 > height) {
        if (yPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0) {
            yPos1 = circleRadius1;
        }else{
            yPos1 = height - circleRadius1;
        }
        yVel1 *= -1;
    }
    if (xPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0 || xPos1 + circleRadius1 > width) {
        if (xPos1 - circleRadius1 < 0) {
            xPos1 = circleRadius1;
        } else {
            xPos1 = width - circleRadius1;
        }
        xVel1 *= -1;
    }
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Rect surfaceFrame = holder.getSurfaceFrame();
    width = surfaceFrame.width();
    height = surfaceFrame.height();
    xPos = width / 2;
    yPos = circleRadius;
    xPos1 = width / 2;
    yPos1 = circleRadius1;
    updateThread = new UpdateThread(this);
    updateThread.setRunning(true);
    updateThread.start();
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    updateThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            updateThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is UpdateThread.java

```
package com.example.movements;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
public class UpdateThread extends Thread {
private long time;
private final int fps = 20;
private boolean toRun = false;
private MovementView movementView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
public UpdateThread(MovementView rMovementView) {
    movementView = rMovementView;
    surfaceHolder = movementView.getHolder();
}
public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    toRun = run;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (toRun) {
        long cTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((cTime - time) <= (1000 / fps)) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                movementView.updatePhysics();
                movementView.onDraw(c);
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
        time = cTime;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: google for *coefficient of restitution* or *elastic collision*

Answer (score 1):

To check wether they are hitting each other, you can just check if the distance between their centers is smaller than (radius*2). To make a nice deflection, you'll have to do some math that's beyond me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532891/angle-that-a-moving-ball-will-bounce-off-of-an-inert-ball) is another answer on that.

I've googled it a bit and apparantly the term used in physics for this problem is called elastic collision. I've found a nice tutorial on the subject [here](https://sites.google.com/site/t3hprogrammer/research/circle-circle-collision-tutorial) (especially the dynamic circle-circle collision bit). Also, [here](http://www.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/ntnujava/index.php?topic=2203.0) is an applet which demonstrates this. The source code for this can be found [here]

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation